# Why is an ellipse not a self-intersecting curve?

Tags: classical-mechanics, terminology, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, non-linear-systems

For a Hamiltonian which is time-independent, the phase trajectories don't intersect. But the Hamiltonian of a one-dimensional harmonic oscillator with constant energy, for example, has an elliptical phase trajectory. Since the phase space point comes back to the same point of the trajectory, how is an ellipse not a self-intersecting curve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of Hamiltonian mechanics, fixing initial condition (x and p for 2 dimensional system) uniquely fixes the time evolution. The trajectories in phase space can not intersect, because if it does then for same initial condition one can have multiple trajectories. For a periodic trajectory (circle or ellipse) no such problem arises. That is why elliptic trajectories are allowed. Whether you can call it self intersecting or not, I think, is a question of nomenclature.

Comment: The naïve idea of a "self-intersecting curve" is that the curve intersects itself at one, or several, *discrete* points, like the intersections on a road map. A closed curve like an ellipse could be considered to "intersect itself" at *every* point on the curve, but that idea doesn't lead to anthing very useful.